# Detect a memory growth

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode

I have a memory growth seen in xcode instruments, so after trying to eliminate the problem, i have seen that in my audio buffer callback method, there is a block of code that when i erase, the problem is been solved.
so , this callback happens many times a second and cause the growth:

```
    static OSStatus recordingCallback(void *inRefCon, 
                                      AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, 
                                      const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, 
                                      UInt32 inBusNumber, 
                                      UInt32 inNumberFrames, 
                                      AudioBufferList *ioData)
    {


        AudioBuffer buffer;

        buffer.mNumberChannels = 1;
        buffer.mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames * 2;
        //NSLog(@"%ld",inNumberFrames);
        buffer.mData = malloc( inNumberFrames * 2 );
        // Put buffer in a AudioBufferList
        AudioBufferList bufferList;
        bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
        bufferList.mBuffers[0] = buffer;



        OSStatus status;
        status = AudioUnitRender(audioUnit, 
                                 ioActionFlags, 
                                 inTimeStamp, 
                                 inBusNumber, 
                                 inNumberFrames, 
                                 &bufferList); 
..
..
..
 free(buffer.mData);
```

can you see some line here that can cause that? the `buffer.mdata` is free.
there is something else that i dont free, that is growing .

thanks.

Comment: Where does your AudioBufferList get freed?

Comment: What have you replaced with `..`? Is there any `return` statement in there per chance?

Comment: no return in there, and AudioBufferList was not released. is it allocated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to release your `bufferList`.

Comment: anyone ?  this line is ok? :int16_t *q = (int16_t *)(&bufferList)->mBuffers[0].mData; ? or need a release?

Comment: To me it looks like it's created on the stack: `AudioBufferList bufferList;`, the same for the buffer: `AudioBuffer buffer;` so there is no need to `free()` it.